# MvvmCross + Xamarin.iOs workflow

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, xamarin-studio

I am working on creation MvvmCross mobile application for iOS. 
I create logic on my windows machine with visual studio and then create designs with xamarin studio on my mac.

I use n+1 mvvmcross as examples and there Stuart editing views with Xcode designer tool(maybe back that time there was no iOS designer integrated to xamarin studio). 
The problems is that when I edit view through Xcode designer and save it's not always sync with xamarin studio(designer) and when it does layout might be broken(not the same as I made in Xcode).

I tired to edit views with xamarin studio build in designer and have the same problems that after rebuild layout might get broken. Behavior is unpredictable.
Another problem is that controls might get disappeared from designer, I can see them in Document outline but not in the view builder.

So my questions are: what is the best workflow(no meter personal preferences, just the most stable way to develop)? 
and what can cause these problems?

Comment: That looks that you may be missconfiguring some auto-layouts in the designer. Are you using constraints? do you see any orange handler (wrong constraint) in the designer? When that happens, the view can be totally hidden.

Comment: I tried with constraints and without. Need to check about orange handler. This happens mostly when I have some text field or label with table view.

Comment: I checked, yes, all of my table views were orange, after I fix those, it start shoving properly. Now I ran into other problem, when I set all sizes and constraints for the table view, after rebuild it gets broken(resizes to initial size) and orange but when I ran it on the device, it shows like it should be, any ideas?